# ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'set'

Tags: python, excel, postgresql

I am importing Excel data into postgreSQL using Python and running into an Programming Error. I did research the issue and found out it has something to do with postgreSQL. Can someone please provide assistance.

```
import psycopg2
import xlrd

book = xlrd.open_workbook("T:\data.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("HCSData")
database = psycopg2.connect (database = "", user="")

cursor = database.cursor()
delete = """Drop table if exists "Python".hcsdata"""
print (delete)
mydata = cursor.execute(delete)

cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE "Python".hcsdata
   (DCAD_Prop_ID   varchar(55),
   Address VARCHAR(50),
   Addition          VARCHAR(100),
   Block  text,
   Lot   integer,
   Permit_Num           varchar(55),
   Permit_Date             date,
   Foundation_Date  date,
   Frame_Date   date,
   Final_Date    date,
   HCS     varchar(55),
   Project_ID   integer
   );''')
print "Table created successfully"

query = """INSERT INTO "Python".hcsdata (DCAD_Prop_ID,Address,Addition, Block, Lot,
Permit_Num,Permit_Date, Foundation_Date, Frame_Date, Final_Date, HCS,Project_ID)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

for r in range(1, sheet.nrows):
    DCAD_Prop_ID = sheet.cell(r,0).value
    Address = sheet.cell(r,1).value
    Addition = sheet.cell(r,2).value
    Block = sheet.cell(r,3).value
    Lot = sheet.cell(r,4).value
    Permit_Num = sheet.cell(r,5).value
    Permit_Date = None if not sheet.cell(r,6).value else xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(sheet.cell(r,6).value,book.datemode)
    Foundation_Date = None if not sheet.cell(r,7).value else xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(sheet.cell(r,7).value,book.datemode)
    Frame_Date = None if not sheet.cell(r,8).value else xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(sheet.cell(r,8).value,book.datemode)
    Final_Date = None if not sheet.cell(r,9).value else xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(sheet.cell(r,9).value,book.datemode)
    HCS = sheet.cell(r,10).value
    Project_ID =sheet.cell(r,11).value

    values = (DCAD_Prop_ID,set(Address),Addition, Block, Lot,
Permit_Num,Permit_Date, Foundation_Date, Frame_Date, Final_Date, HCS,Project_ID)

    cursor.execute(query, values)

cursor.close()

database.commit()

database.close()

print ""
print "All Done! Bye, for now."
print ""
columns = str(sheet.ncols)
rows = str(sheet.nrows)
print "Done"
```

And the error Python shows is:

```
Drop table if exists "Python".hcsdata
Table created successfully

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Programming\PythonSQLNew\HCSData.py", line 53, in <module>
cursor.execute(query, values)
ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'set'
```

Comment: are you sure of `set(Address)` ? if you need unicity you should probably do `list(set(Address))`. But I suspect it should just be `Address`.

Comment: Thanks Jean, do you think the error is at Address?

Comment: I'm quite sure. Try to pass something else. I'd do that.

Comment: I tried list(set(Address)) in the for r in range but it showed an error.

Comment: just try `Address`. If you don't know why you put a `set` in the first place, then that's a "typo".

Comment: It worked great, thanks Jean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your query seem to expect all strings:

```
query = """INSERT INTO "Python".hcsdata (DCAD_Prop_ID,Address,Addition, Block, Lot,
Permit_Num,Permit_Date, Foundation_Date, Frame_Date, Final_Date, HCS,Project_ID)
VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s,%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
```

In your values there are almost only strings but an alien stands out:

```
values = (DCAD_Prop_ID,set(Address),Addition, Block, Lot,
Permit_Num,Permit_Date, Foundation_Date, Frame_Date, Final_Date, HCS,Project_ID)
```

I admit the message is cryptic, but the logic tells us to do just:

```
values = (DCAD_Prop_ID,Address,Addition, Block, Lot,
Permit_Num,Permit_Date, Foundation_Date, Frame_Date, Final_Date, HCS,Project_ID)
```

(since there's no need to put `Address` in a `set`, it seems to be a string like the other fields)

Answer (score 4):

For future people perhaps trying to use e.g. `varchar[]` or `WHERE x IN %(values)s`, you need to convert the `set` to a `tuple`.

Comment: And for even more future people who use psycopg3, it has to be a `list` instead of a `tuple` (and also `WHERE x = ANY(%s)`).