# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'set'

Tags: python, discord, psycopg2

There is this discord bot. I wan't to create for my server. But i used psycopg2 because i wan't it to create a list of projects ideas. And i got this error `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'set'` there is my code:

```
import psycopg2
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host="ec2-3-216-92-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
        database="d1vpende403347",
        user="hnzgmwsoiogmmt",
        password="86bfca0c982e04ae0ca6e6f4d1f4fb03ca5f4f4cb9a911672fa993a300e7ea0e",
        port=5432)
bot=discord.Client()
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
cursor=conn.cursor()

@bot.command()
async def rules(ctx):
    await ctx.send("1. To enter our server, you have of course to learn python and some libraries, for example: 'discord.py', 'django'.\n2. No insults or bad words.\n3.Enjoy it.")
@bot.command()
async def new(ctx, author:discord.Member, project):
    name=author.display_name
    await ctx.send(f"There is your entry: The author: {name} , project: {project}")
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO ideas(author,project) VALUES(%s,%s)",({name},{project}))
    await ctx.send("The entry was succesfully added""")

print("And There it is, you're connected")

TOKEN=os.environ.get("DISCORD_BOT_SECRET")
bot.run(TOKEN)

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

thx for the response

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'set'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347497/programmingerror-cant-adapt-type-set)

Comment: no, i found the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import psycopg2
import os
from discord.ext import commands
import discord

conn = psycopg2.connect(
        host="ec2-3-216-92-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com",
        database="d1vpende403347",
        user="hnzgmwsoiogmmt",
        password="86bfca0c982e04ae0ca6e6f4d1f4fb03ca5f4f4cb9a911672fa993a300e7ea0e",
        port=5432)
bot=discord.Client()
bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
cursor=conn.cursor()

@bot.command()
async def rules(ctx):
    await ctx.send("1. To enter our server, you have of course to learn python and some libraries, for example: 'discord.py', 'django'.\n2. No insults or bad words.\n3.Enjoy it.")
@bot.command()
async def new(ctx, author:discord.Member, project):
    name=author.display_name
    await ctx.send(f"There is your entry: The author: {name} , project: {project}")
    cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO ideas(author,project) VALUES(%s,%s)",(name,project))
    await ctx.send("The entry was succesfully added""")

print("And There it is, you're connected")

TOKEN=os.environ.get("DISCORD_BOT_SECRET")
bot.run(TOKEN)

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: it's the answer

Comment: when you post an answer, it would be more helpful if you describe the fix, instead of just reposting the code block with mods, especially a sizable block like that one.  I ended up having to load them in two browser windows and compare line-by-line - and even then it was difficult to spot the differences.  Just sayin'...